Proving the claim that $||A||_2 \leq ||A||_F$
Claim. Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$. Our claim is $||A||_2 \leq ||A||_F$.
I attach my proof attempt. I would like to ask, if my proof is rigorous and technically correct.
Proof.
$$ \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}$$
Let
$$A := (a_{ij})$$
$$ 
y^H := \begin{bmatrix}
\tilde{y}_0 & \tilde{y}_1 & \ldots & \tilde{y}_{m-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
x := \begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
x_1 \\
\vdots \\
x_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\norm{A}_2^2 &= \max_{\norm{x}_2 = \norm{y}_2 = 1} |y^H A x|  & \{\text{Definition}\}\\
&= \max_{\norm{x}_2 = \norm{y}_2 = 1} \Biggl|\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \tilde{y}_{i} a_{ij} x_j \Biggr|\\
&\leq \max_{\norm{x}_2 = \norm{y}_2 = 1} \left\{\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}  |\tilde{y}_{i}| \Biggl|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_{ij} x_j\Biggr| \right\} & \{\text{Triangle Inequality}\}\\
&\leq \max_{\norm{x}_2 = \norm{y}_2 = 1} \left\{ \left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}  |\tilde{y}_{i}|^2 \right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \Biggl|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_{ij} x_j\Biggr|^2 \right)^{1/2} \right\} & \{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}\}\\
&= \max_{\norm{x}_2 } \left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \Biggl|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_{ij} x_j\Biggr|^2 \right)^{1/2}& \{\norm{y}_2 = 1\}\\
&\leq \max_{\norm{x}_2 } \left[\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|a_{ij} x_j|\right)^2 \right]^{1/2}& \{\text{Triangle Inequality}\}\\
&\leq \max_{\norm{x}_2 } \left[\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \left\{ \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|a_{ij}|^2\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} |x_j|^2\right)^{1/2}\right\}^2 \right]^{1/2}& \{\text{Cauchy Schwarz}\}\\
&= \max_{\norm{x}_2 } \left[\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|a_{ij}|^2\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} |x_j|^2\right) \right]^{1/2}\\
&= \left[\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|a_{ij}|^2\right)\right]^{1/2} & \{\norm{x}_2 = 1\}\\
&= \norm{A}_F
\end{align*}
$$
Also, consider
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then, $\norm{A}_2 = \norm{A}_F = 1$. So, the inequality $\norm{A}_2 \leq \norm{A}_F$ is tight. This closes the proof. $\blacksquare$

Looks correct. Or can be proved by $\lambda_{\max}(A^HA) \leq \sum \lambda(A^HA)$

Your start is not correct. On the left you have $A$ in the second power, while on the right it is only in first power. // You do not need the triangle inequality for the second invocation of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Looks fine save for a couple of typos. Just a style point: You can save yourself from having to write a load of square roots by keeping everything squared from start to finish. And you can save yourself around 4 lines at the beginning by starting with the definition
$$||A||_2^2=\max_{||x||_2=1}||Ax||_2^2.$$

While this question has already received a good answer, I see value in writing the suggested analysis using a single sum.
With $$A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \dotsc & a_n \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$x = (x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)^T$$ the triangle inequality implies that $$\|Ax\|_2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \|a_j\| _2|x_j|.$$
We then view the right hand side as an inner product between the real vectors $$\alpha = (\|a_1\|,\|a_2\|,\dotsc,\|a_n\|)^T$$ and $$\beta = (|x_1|,|x_2|,\dotsc,|x_n|)^T$$
and apply Cauchy-Schwart's inequality. We find
$$\|Ax\| \leq \|\alpha\|_2 \|\beta\|_2 = \|A\|_F \|x\|_2.$$
It follows that $$\|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_F.$$
